# Docker (windows) : docker container ls / docker image list suddenly shows nothing

Tags: docker

not sure what i did wrong here, but i installed a new docker image and ran it - then i installed 2 additional images.

when i ran a ls here - they showed up fine, and i was also able to connect to the container.

then i opened docker desktop for windows - and saw a 'switch to WSL' button, and just tried to click it to see what it did and then i ran ls again and it showed nothing in the list.

assumed that it went to my WSL2 - so i switched back to windows (stopped the WSL2 option in docker settings ).

The strange thing here now is :

1) ls shows only :

```
C:\Users\mtd\.docker>docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

C:\Users\mtd\.docker>
```

2) i am - still - able to connect to my docker container via a browser.

i tried :

```
docker ps - & docker ps -a
```

but all shows nothing.

I also tried this command :

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

to see if i could switch back and forth but nomatter what - the list of containers is blank.

Edit:

After a reboot - i now get this error :

```
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

I then tried to run switchdeamon a few times but now it just keeps coming with this error above - and after a few times i can do a docker container ls again - but still all images gone.

It was working smooth from commandline until i fired up the docker desktop :/

Comment: Restart doctor or system

Comment: i updated my post - restarted and then it started throwing errors. Got it going with no error but my images are still gone.

Comment: So seems like dockor is not running now, run with administrator privileges

Comment: tried that too, all seems to be gone. i can call docker - but still everythng is blank

Comment: Try to restart from command shell or check https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2671

Comment: Or docker ls in cmd that is open with administrator privileges

Comment: i tried to run as admin - i decided now to uninstall and reinstall docker desktop and try not to switch between WSL2 and Windows anymore - seems thats where things crashed things up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199137/discussion-between-adiii-and-mdtp).